# How ordering functionality works in article manager of Joomla Admin?

Tags: joomla

Hello i m new to joomla and i want to know how 'ordering of article' in article manager works? and also how ordering of article is changed if i modify the ordering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have two or more articles that have the same `Section` and `Category` then ordering starts coming into play with articles ordered *1*, *2*, *3* etc. The result is that if you decide to demonstrate all articles of that particular Section and Category combination, then they would appear on that particular order.